# For loop only returning last item

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops

```
# Create random df
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10, size=(100,23)))
test = df[:50]  

for i in range(len(test)):
    query_node = test.iloc[i]
    # Find the distance between this node and everyone else
    euclidean_distances = test.apply(lambda row: distance.euclidean(row, query_node), axis=1)
    # Create a new dataframe with distances.
    distance_frame = pd.DataFrame(data={"dist": euclidean_distances, "idx": euclidean_distances.index})
    distance_frame.sort_values("dist", inplace=True)
    smallest_dist = [dist["idx"] for idx, dist in distance_frame.iloc[1:4].iterrows()]
```

I am stumped on this problem and wondering if anyone can see where I'm going wrong. I am trying to calculate the euclidean distance between each row and every other row. Then, I sort those distances and return the index positions of the "most similar" rows by minimum distance in the list smallest_dist.

The issue is that this only returns the most similar index positions of the last row: [6.0, 3.0, 4.0]

What I want for output is something like this:

| Original ID | Matches |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4,5,6 |
| 2 | 8,2,5 |

I've tried this but it gives the same result:

```
list_of_mins = []

for i in range(len(test)):
    query_node = test.iloc[i]
    # Find the distance between this node and everyone else
    euclidean_distances = test.apply(lambda row: distance.euclidean(row, query_node), axis=1)
    # Create a new dataframe with distances.
    distance_frame = pd.DataFrame(data={"dist": euclidean_distances, "idx": euclidean_distances.index})
    distance_frame.sort_values("dist", inplace=True)
    smallest_dist = [dist["idx"] for idx, dist in distance_frame.iloc[1:4].iterrows()]
    for i in range(len(test)):
        list_of_mins.append(smallest_dist_ixs)

Does anyone know what's causing this problem? thank you!
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the distance library available so I change that to a simple sum, but it should work after replacing it back to distance

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(100, 23)))
test = df[:50]

dict_results = {'ids': [],
                'ids_min': []}

n_min = 2

for i in range(len(test)):
    query_node = test.iloc[i]
    # Find the distance between this node and everyone else
    euclidean_distances = test.apply(lambda row: np.sum(row), axis=1)
    # Create a new dataframe with distances.
    # print(euclidean_distances)
    distance_frame = pd.DataFrame(data={"dist": euclidean_distances,
                                        "idx": euclidean_distances.index})

    selected_min = distance_frame.sort_values("dist").head(n_min)
    dict_results['ids'].append(i)
    dict_results['ids_min'].append(', '.join(selected_min['idx'].astype('str')))

print(pd.DataFrame(dict_results))
```

I added a few changes to your code:

1. Added a `n_min` parameter to define how many elements you want in the second columns (number of index to closest rows)
2. Created a dict where the results are going to be save to create the data frame you want.
3. In the loop added the append to add the results of each iteration to the dict where the results are being saved
4. After the loop if you call the dict inside pd.DataFrame it will be parse the same way you were doing it with the `distance_frame`

Comment: Hi! This helped tremendously, thank you! It worked great

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try to resturn the results either in the data frame or (for convenience of testing) a dictionary? For example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10, size=(100,23)))
test = df[:50]
closest_nodes = {}

for i in range(len(test)):
    query_node = test.iloc[i]
    # Find the distance between this node and everyone else
    euclidean_distances = test.apply(lambda row: distance.euclidean(row, query_node), axis=1)
    # Create a new dataframe with distances.
    distance_frame = pd.DataFrame(data={"dist": euclidean_distances, "idx": euclidean_distances.index})
    distance_frame.sort_values("dist", inplace=True)
    closest_nodes[i] = [dist["idx"] for idx, dist in distance_frame.iloc[1:4].iterrows()]
```

The thing I didn't see in your code was some sort of storage action to put the one result per test case into a permanent structure.

Comment: Hi thank you for your response - this also worked great and fit perfectly into my code!